# How to add Jquery cdn in ScriptManager and if the load fail then load from local file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cdn, scriptmanager

In asp:ScriptManager i load jquery like this.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMasterPage" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/tag-it.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/MosJScript.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.tools.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.dragsort.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.ad-gallery.pack.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Suppose that i would like to use jquery cdn from google but if the cdn file fail to load then i would load from local machine instead. how to do this.

Comment: I'd really question whether you want to do this via code in your HTML... The load time of the page is could be horrible when the CDN does fail - imagine if the CDN is slow and takes a long time to timeout, it's going to block the page until the timeout has elapsed for each element... If you can't trust the CDN use a different CDN i.e. one you can trust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something similar to [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/01/21/using-cdn-hosted-jquery-with-a-local-fall-back-copy.aspx).  The search term is 'fall-back' file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
{
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks it seems that we can't use this in ScriptManager, right ?

Comment: You can always put that chunk of script inside a script file and include it in ScriptManager.  Note: I do not know enough about the execution sequence of ScriptManager to know if it respects order.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a Script Resource Mapping Definition. See the document below for example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.scriptresourcemapping

Then you have to set EnableCdn property of ScriptManager to true, to enable the usage of CDN.